# Incredibly low performance of Contacts app in Moto Z / Android 8

Tags: performance, google-contacts, motorola-moto-z2-play

My 4 GB/64 GB/8 core Moto Z2 is incredibly slow when it comes to built in Contacts app. I.e.:

- it requires at least 3-4 seconds to open it up,
- it needs at least 2-3 seconds to exchange phone numbers with corresponding contacts in dial log.

It has nothing to do with the battery charge (happens all the time, on charge level between 10-100%) and has also nothing to do with overall system performance (both system and all other apps are working as fast as possible / expected; Contacts is the only problematic application).

I have 95 applications installed. None of them are performance-hungry and many system services (i.e. Google+, Google Assistant, YouTube, Google Drive, Google Play Music / Movies, Photos, etc.) disabled, because I am not using them.

Is there anything I can do to fix this problem (except for replacing Contacts with something else)?

Comment: Are you having a tremendous number of contacts?

Comment: Define "tremendous"? :> 285 doesn't sound like "that much", am I correct?